# gpg: Decrypt to original filename without warning

Tags: gpg

`gpg` lets you decrypt data and save it to a file with the same filename as the original file using `--use-embedded-filename`. How do I do this without raising the warning as seen below?

```
$ gpg --encrypt --recipient user filename.txt
$ mv filename.txt.gpg snafu.gpg
$ cat snafu.gpg | gpg --use-embedded-filename
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ... 
$ ls
filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You may ask `gpg` to be quiet with `--quiet`:

```
gpg --quiet --use-embedded-filename snafu.gpg
```

Comment: That does work, but isn't there a dedicated command keyword for this purpose? `--decrypt` insists on writing to stdout, and `--output` wants a filename, so what to do?

Comment: @forthrin Yes, all of that is true, which is why I suggested using `--quiet` to get rid of the warning.

Comment: `--quiet` sounds more like "suppress warning" rather than "I want to decrypt a file", but if this is the only way, or even the correct and intended way, then OK. I'll leave the question open for a while to check for alternatives.