# Find an option other than --quiet to avoid GPG warning when a file is decrypted

Tags: gpg

##### GPG decrypt command

I'm try to decrypt a file by `gpg` and to do this I'm executing (with success) the following command:

```
gpg --passphrase "12345678" --batch --yes --no-symkey-cache filename.tar.gz.gpg
```

The result of the execution of the command is:

- the file `filename.tar.gz.gpg` is correctly decrypted and is created the file `filename.tar.gz`;
- by the options `--passphrase "12345678" --batch --yes`
  the GUI for the insertion of the passphrase is not open.

##### GPG Warning and `--quiet` option

But there is a problem: the `gpg` execution of the previous command produces the following warning:

```
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
```

and the correct output:

```
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
```

By [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441997/gpg-decrypt-to-original-filename-without-warning/441998#441998), I know that by the option `--quiet`, the previous `gpg` command doesn't produce any output message.

The warning seems tell that in my command is not present the request to decrypt the file `filename.tar.gz.gpg`.

##### My question

So my question is:
Is there a way to tell to `gpg` that it must decrypt a file to avoid the warning `no command supplied.`?

Comment: The warning of GPG having to guess which command you wanted to use would probably go away if you used a command for `gpg` such as `--encrypt` or `--decrypt`.

Comment: @GracefulRestart If I add `--decrypt`, the command becomes `gpg --passphrase "12345678" --batch --yes --no-symkey-cache --decrypt filename.tar.gz.gpg`, but its execution  sends the output to STDOUT and the `filename.tar.gz` is not created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Solution: option `--output` and command `--decrypt`

Thanks to @GracefulRestart and to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474247/writing-gpg-decrypted-file-to-a-specified-outfile/18474305#18474305) (which explains me how to set the target of the output of `gpg`), I have finally found the command suited for my needs:

```
gpg --passphrase "12345678" --batch --yes --output filename.tar.gz --no-symkey-cache --decrypt filename.tar.gz.gpg
```

In the command I have added 2 options:

- `--output filename.tar.gz` which allows writing the output of the command `gpg` to the file `filename.tar.gz`
- the command `--decrypt filename.tar.gz.gpg` as suggested by @GracefulRestart to specify to `gpg` the command to execute

With this modifications and without `--quiet` the warning is not present.

Comment: Note that specifying passwords and passphrases on the command line is not recommended, because of the history feature in most shells, and the full command line being present in the list of processes. If you really don't want to type in your passphrase, consider not having one, or using something like [pam-gnupg](https://github.com/cruegge/pam-gnupg).

Comment: @Vilinkameni The previous command will be executed from a C compiled program. Do you know if it is put inside the history or not? I know that is an other question but if you want add here a comment about this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Obviously, if you are using `exec*` family of functions, they are front ends to a system call, so they aren't related to a shell. If your program uses Readline and allows the user to edit that command using it, that is similar to using a shell: Readline has the history feature. However, the full command line is still visible in the list of processes, as stated.

Comment: @Vilinkameni My program doesn't use Readline. Remains the problem of the list of processes. But this can be the topic of an other question. For the current question I have found the solution and the warning is gone away. Thank you.